# How to find of user exists in mysql table using peewee ORM?

Tags: python, mysql-python, peewee, flask-peewee

I have this table in mysql,

```
import peewee

class User(peewee.Model):

    username = peewee.Charfield(max_length=60)
    email = peewee.Charfield(max_length=300)

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<User: {}>".format(self.username)
```

when I try the below code for an existing user:

```
User.get(email="zhaochang@qq.com")
```

it returns `<User: zhaochang>`

but for a random email/user that dose not exists `User.get(email="some_random@email.com")` it throws error:

UserDoesNotExist: `Instance matching query does not exist:`

`SQL: SELECT 't1'.'id', 't1'.'email', 't1'.'username' FROM 'user' AS t1 WHERE ('t1'.'email' = %s)`
`PARAMS: [u'some_random@email.com']`

I was expecting for User.get method to return None.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would you expect the method to return None when the documentation clearly states that

> If no model is returned, a DoesNotExist is raised.

Source: http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/api.html#Model.get

Comment: i read that in documentation and used how it is showin in example. thanks